# Me-dá está gramaticamente certo?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

Eu sempre usava **me-dá** para pedir alguém me dar alguma coisa. Acabei de ler um texto e achei:

> Dê-me o livro.

Sei que gramaticalmente esta frase está certa. Mas por que é que algumas pessoas dizem:

> Me-dá o livro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário esclarecer primeiro que há duas dimensões para a resposta:

1) oralidade *vs* registro escrito

2) diversidade da língua em função dos regionalismos

Primeiro, as gramáticas servem para regulamentar o registro escrito da língua, que é uma expressão necessária para, por exemplo, redigir leis, contratos e acordos internacionais e outros documentos, nos quais objetiva-se, entre outros, reduzir ao mínimo a possibilidade de ambiguidade ou, mais especificamente, a multiplicidade semantica.  A partir do referencial de alguma linguagem falada, cria-se uma codificação de como essa lingua deverá ser registrada em escrito até que ocorra uma reforma ortográfica.

Contudo, língua não é o que a gramática fixa, mas sim o que os seus falantes a fazem ser.  Nesse sentido, a lingua falada é um ser vivo, com vontade própria e que se recusa a ser algemada.  Multiplicidade de sentidos (polissemia) é justamente o que os poetas e compositores buscam, incluindo novas expressões sintáticas.  Assim, ao invés de aceitar o jugo da lingua escrita, a lingua falada vai derivando do referencial histórico que foi congelado na gramática e, quando a lingua falada já derivou o suficiente ao ponto da mútua não inteligibilidade com a língua escrita, faz-se a reforma.

Quanto aos regionalismos, se não estou enganado, a forma "Dá-me um beijo!" ainda é uma forma muitíssimo corriqueira à oralidade de pt-PT, ao passo que é forma rara em pt-BR, onde o "Me dá um beijo!" é quase unanimemente preponderante.

Contudo é mister destacar dois pontos referentes ao hífen:

1) o registro escrito dessa forma, com a anteposição do pronome átono, ocorre

- ou por falta de domínio da "regra culta" (com todos as aspas que se faça jus)
- ou para registrar em escrito propositalmente a oralidade (poesia, depoimentos etc.)

2) qualquer que seja o caso, o que ocorre é uma próclise, que não permite interposição de hífen, como ocorre com a mesóclise e com a ênclise

Apesar disso, as diferenças entre os registros escritos de pt-PT e pt-BR serão muito menos impactantes aos olhos do que serão aos ouvidos as formas orais de pt-PT e pt-BT, beirando a mútua ininteligibilidade em muitos casos.

Answer (score 3):

Eu aprendi na escola que **nunca devemos começar uma frase com o pronome oblíquo átono**. Contudo, o portuguès escrito é uma coisa, e o português falado informalmente é outra.

- Na informalidade, em pt-BR, é muito comum ouvirmos **"te devolvo amanhã"**, **"me empresta o seu livro?"**, **"te amo muito"**.  Em filmes, novelas, e na minha vida pessoal, nunca ouvi alguém dizer "amo-te".  Acho que se eu dissesse isso a alguma mulher, ela sairia correndo.
- Certas formas gramaticais corretas chegam a soar como um pedantismo na língua falada.  É o caso de alguém roubar a sua bolsa em uma rua movimentada, e você gritar: Socorro, ladrão, peguem-no! Peguem-no!  Embora errado, todos gritariam "pega ele", pega ele!"

Respondendo à sua pergunta: está errado.  Não use na língua escrita e evite o uso na língua falada, em situaçõs muito formais.  Em situações informais, é o que se espera ouvir.

Obs: Acho que em Portugal ouve-se a forma correta com mais frequência do que no Brasil.

Comment: Em Portugal não é costume ouvir a forma com o pronome antes; soa brasileiro. Mesmo em situações muito informais: "Socorro, ladrão! Agarrem-no, agarrem-no!" (Como sempre: "asterisco". Dizemos "não me soa bem"... não vou agora escrever uma tese sobre isto, até porque não sou capaz. Tenho conhecimento intuitivo da língua, mas quando se entra por pronomes oblíquos e sintagmas e IPAs e o diabo, parece que ouço o treinador mandar as enxaquecas levantarem-se do banco e aquecer...)

Comment: @ANeves, muito interessante o que disse. Como foi descrito por Centaurus, usar o pronome após o verbo causaria um grande espanto no Brasil, tanto em uma conversa corriqueira quanto em um ambiente culto. O "soa brasileiro" que você disse é no sentido pejorativo, em Portugal?

Comment: @Magela , não, não foi dito com sentido pejorativo. Foi dito com um sentido neutro. Suponho que se pudesse dizer, opostamente, "usar o pronome após o verbo causaria um grande espanto, no Brasil... soaria português." :) Falamos [bastante diferente](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1eSQh3Vp2Q) - e isso é belo.

Comment: @ANeves, minha pergunta foi por pura curiosidade mesmo. Tenho curiosidade em saber como o pt-BR falado é visto por nativos de Portugal? Você poderia matar a curiosidade dessa mente curiosa? :)

Comment: É burrice isto acontecer, mas o português-brasileiro é visto um pouco como ignorante, @Magela, por causa de vários fatores. Eu acho que se destacam três: os brasileiros que cá moram são comummente emigrantes de classe baixa - menos educados que a média; e a falta de concordância (entre sujeito e verbo - tu vai, nós vai; entre artigo-singular e substantivo-plural - os gato, as ideia, etc), que soa terrível aos ouvidos snobs portugueses. Conjugar "tu" com a terceira pessoa do singular, em particular, cai muito mal por cá.

Comment: São preconceitos, que acho expectáveis... como fazer piadas de português que se chama manel, tem bigode, e uma padaria. :) Não devemos ligar demasiado, é provocação de povo-irmão; se for divertido rimos, se for parvo encolhemos os ombros e seguimos. :)

Comment: @ANeves   Realmente há um número considerável de brasileiros que desconhecem regras básicas de gramática.  Quando os ouço, também me doem os ouvidos.  Tu vai na festa da Maria ?  Me dá aqui pra mim ver.  Os menino tá lá dentro.  As casa ficou tudo cheio d'água.  Ela vai vim aqui.   A gente vamos ao cinema.  Fazem dez anos que moro aqui.  Isso não soa terrível só aos ouvidos portugueses.  Também é causa de otalgia nos brasileiros bem alfabetizados.  Infelizmente, acredito  que  cerca de 50% da nossa população de 210 milhões de almas comete esses erros crassos no dia-a-dia,  .

Comment: Nosso sistema educacional precisa de muito investimento, mas infelizmente as verbas são reduzidas cada vez mais.  Seja pela pouca importância que os governantes dão à educação, seja pela corrupção alastrante que não deixa aquele pouco chegar intacto  ao seu destino final.

Comment: @Centaurus, estou totalmente de acordo com você. Esses erros que você citou, realmente doem os ouvidos. Vindo de pessoas que claramente não tiveram oportunidade de estudar, é facilmente relevado. O problema é quando vem de pessoas que tiverem a oportunidade de estudar e assim insistem no erro. Parece-me (dando uma de pt-PT) que gostam de não usar as regras básicas. Não sei. Vale a pena um estudo mais qualitativo e quantitativo.

Comment: ‍♀️ Um passo de cada vez. O Brasil de hoje (50%) é melhor que o Brasil de ontem (60%); que o de amanhã seja tambem melhor que o de hoje, 40% - vai no caminho certo! :) Coragem, oupa, continuemos a trilhar este caminho difícil.